# Why I cannot access a member?

Tags: java, class-members

I have defined the following class:

```
public static class Solution{
   ....
}
```

In class solution I have defined two inner classes:

```
public static class Solution{
   public static class Node{
     int id;
     public double x;
     public double y;
   }
   public static class Tree<Node>{
     Node root;
     boolean contains(Node n){
         if (n == null)
            return false;
        if (n.x == root.x && n.y == root.y)
            return true;
        else
            return ....; //something else
   }
}
```

The problem is that I cannot access `y` and `x` fields of objects `n` and `root` and I dont see why?
EDIT: I cannot separate the Node class because I am writing it for Top Coder and I have to submit only one class; The fields x and y are set as public but still I cannot access them.

Comment: You can also do one thing. Define the Node class outside the Solution class and then try if it works.

Comment: Have you tried `Tree<Solution.Node>` and `Solution.Node root;`? Without seeing your imports (which you haven't included), I can't verify you're not importing another `Node` class.

Comment: Could also try `import Solution.Node;` though I can't test for sure.

Answer (score 4):

Because you hide the `Node` class with the generic `Node` (here: `Tree<Node>`).

```
<T extends Node>
```

So it know it extends Node what you pass to it (and know it have `x` etc.)

Comment: This makes no sense. Where are they supposed to put `T extends Node`? What is `T` going to do?

Comment: It's a generic, T is a generic name for generics. T will say "every class which extends Node" so Node is OK. Please read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/ Remember inside <> you declare the name of the generic NOT THE TYPE!

Comment: I understand what generics are. I don't see how they'll help with the OP's problem.

Comment: Ah, and he is supposted to add this to public static class Tree<T extends Node>. How you can't see how it solve the problem? If you give to a generic the same name of a class ofcourse the class will be hidden by the generic. And generic extends Object, so it don't have x etc.

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer.  If OP replaces `public static class Tree<Node>` with `public static class Tree<N>` I would guess it would be more obvious.

Comment: @emory Oh dear lord, thank you. That totally threw me off; it now makes sense what the problem is. Marco, I'd probably explain what Emory is pointing out.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno Thanks, it worked! One question: I thought that I use <> to declare the type, which obviously is not the case. How should I declare the type?

Comment: In this case you don't need generics at all since you need only Node class in your method. But, you should give to the generic a name (T for example) and then you can use T extends X to say that objects you pass to it will extends class X. But really, you don't need generics here.

Comment: Because in generics, your code is basically saying `In class Tree, there is an unknown type 'Node' (not related to your previous class definition).` It's not based off of anything, so it's common parent is `Object`. Now, the objects passed to your `contains` method are assumed to be `Objects`, thus not having `x` or `y`. What Marco's answer tells you is that you need to define a type `T` (that replaces `Node`) that is **based off of** a `Node`, making passed objects have the common ancestor `Node`, thus giving you access to `x` and `y`.